# vmware ESXi 5.0 - How to open console locally?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I configured the esxi firewall to restrictive. Now I have no remote access anymore. I can't use ssh or the vSphere client. But I have access to the server via KVM. So I can see the screen and control the mouse and keyboard.

Is it possible to deactivate the firewall?

I think I found the [commands](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005284) I need to run,

but I don't know how to open the console locally.

Can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log in, get to the menu, select "Troubleshooting Options", and enable the shell.

Then, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access the console.